How to bind to ancestor property in code behind
I have tried to do this using binding with element name instead of x:Bind, but it simply doesn’t work in winui. Can someone show a working example where you for example bind a button inside a list view to the ancestor and to a property in the code behind file?
What I have tried simplified is:
  <ListView
      x:Name="View"
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Model.Objects, Mode=OneWay}"
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <StackPanel Margin="8" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">            
                      <Button
                          x:Name="SomeButton
                          Visibility="{Binding Path=PropertyInCodeBehind, ElementName=View//or even the user control">
                      </Button>
                  </StackPanel>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>


It's possible but you need to be more specific to show you a working example. What happens when the button is clicked? Does the button need to be bound to a command in ViewModel or just a click event handler? What is bound to a property in code-behind?

Let’s do it simple. Let’s say you have a bool in the code behind that defines whether the button should be visible. The button is inside the list view, and the list view source is bound to a collection in the view model. Hence, you should bind to the ancestor. I tried naming the user component and then using element name to refer to it, but it stays visible no matter what. Isn’t that the correct approach?

Here is a working example based on your comment:
Shell.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUIApp5.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIApp5"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="RootPage"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <ToggleSwitch
            Grid.Row="0"
            Header="Show Buttons"
            IsOn="{x:Bind ViewModel.ShowButtons, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                    <Button
                        Content="{x:Bind}"
                        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=RootPage, Path=ViewModel.ShowButtons, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Page>

Shell.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class Shell : Page
{
    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ShellViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}

ShellViewModel.cs
public partial class ShellViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items =
        [
        "Item #1",
        "Item #2",
        "Item #3",
        ];

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _showButtons = false;
}

BoolToVisibilityConverter.cs
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}

Remarks

The Shell page is named with x:Name to access it from inside the ItemTemplate.
I'm using the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package for MVVM.


This is very similar to what I have done actually. One question, do the binding still need to be observable?

You mean the ShowButton property? Then yes, if the value is expected to change. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged but the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm helps you with that.

Also, in my case the property is not in the model but in the .xaml.cs file

It never changes. It just needs to be read once during start up

Generally speaking, it should be in the ViewModel. Otherwise, you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged by yourself without the help of the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. If you need to access it from the code-behind(*.xaml.cs), you can simply do ViewModel.ShowButtons.

If it never changes, it could be on the code-behind then.
